# Convergence of the series of a product implication

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I am a bit confused about the following. Suppose that
\begin{equation*} 
\lim_n \sum^n_{i=1} a^{n-i}b_i < \infty \quad (*)
\end{equation*}
where $a\in(0,1)$ and $b_i$ is some non-negative sequence. I was wondering if it is possible for $b_i$ to diverge $b_i \rightarrow \infty$ or whether it has to converge to something necessarily given the above.

If $b_i=b^i$, then, unless I did a mistake,
$$
 \sum^n_{i=1} a^{n-i}b^i = \frac{a^nb-ab^n}{a-b}
$$
hence for $(*)$ to hold it has to be the case that $b_i=b^i$ converges. Does $(*)$ imply in general that $b_i$ must converge? Or can it diverge?

Comment: $b_n \le \sum^n_{i=1} a^{n-i}b_i$, so $b_n \to \infty$ is not possible.